# MVC post list of objects with property of SortedDictionary type

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, post, sorteddictionary

im working on an mvc project and im stuck with posting an unknown number of values (complex object) - input fields are javascript generated.
The problem is that on form POST, the properties of type SortedDictionary are empty.

Here is how all of it looks like:
The controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult AddLocation(CompanyLocationModel model)
{
    ...do something with the model ...
}
```

The CompanyLocationModel(simplified):

```
public class CompanyLocationModel
    {
        public CompanyLocationModel()
        {
            WorkingHours = new List<WorkingHour>();
        }

        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public List<WorkingHour> WorkingHours { get; set; }
        .....
    }
```

The working hour class:

```
public class WorkingHour
{
    public WorkingHour()
    {
        Hours = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();
    }
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public SortedDictionary<DateTime, DateTime> Hours { get; set; }
}
```

How the html should look like?
I've tried this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="WorkingHours[0].DayOfWeek" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="WorkingHours[0].Hours[08:00]" value="16:00">
... repeat n times...
```

and this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="WorkingHours[0].DayOfWeek" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="WorkingHours[0].Hours.Key" value="08:00">
<input type="hidden" name="WorkingHours[0].Hours.Value" value="16:00">
... repeat n times...
```

But it doesnt work. The WorkingHours list is submited and I get the DayOfWeek value of each item on POST, but the Hours value is empty.

Comment: I think because `.Hours` is a `SortedDictionary`, it can have multiple key/value pairs, so you should include an index after `.Hours` (ie. `.Hours[0].Key`). If you only wanted one pair, then use a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: For each list item there will be only one Hours pair, but still, neither of the options i've tried works.

Comment: In that case, why not have a `.StartHour` property and `.EndHour` property? If that doesn't work, you probably need to format the time differently than you're currently doing...

Comment: i cant modify the models of the project. i have to work with it as its created(dont know the reason why its created like this).

Comment: WorkingHours[0].Hours[0].Key worked, thanks :). i thought the Key,Value par was sufficient

Comment: Yeah I guess KeyValuePairs can't be used in models because they're structs... Glad it's working!